# Is there something like remove(bool) in jQuery? if not, how to create an extension?

Tags: jquery

I know this exists:

```
  $(".something").remove()
```

(1) **Is there something like this?**

```
  $(".something").remove(false);  // Don't remove
  $(".something").remove(true);  // Do remove
```

(2) **If not, how can I extend `$`?**

I think the answer to my first question, (1), is "no", because I've read the documentation, but I think this is inconsistent with other methods like `.toggle(bool)` or `prop("..", bool)`

Comment: Why would you want this? Wouldn't this suffice `if(shouldRemove) { //remove } else { //dont remove }`

Comment: that one-line-if would be inconsistent with my other ifs, lol.. and I need to do this with a lot of elements

Comment: It was only one line since I made a comment. It should of course be on several lines. And regarding "lots of elements", sometime you just have to bite the dust and do the refactor :)

Comment: Regarding the first question: "Why would you want this?", we could ask the same question to people out there using toggle(bool) or prop("checked", bool) or prop("disabled", bool)... why arent these people using ifs? if (bool) { o.show } else { o.hide }

Comment: `.prop` et al. is exempt because it relates to state of an elements property. What I'm debating is that you want to hide this in an API that is ambiguous. `Person.getAge(shouldGetAge);`. Why ask for the age if you don't want it? To relate, why call for a removal of element if you don't want to remove it.

Comment: In UI terms, hide/show is somehow similar to remove/not-remove. Sometimes one wants to show or hide temporally something in your UI and sometimes you want to show or hide forever in your UI (ie: remove or not remove). I agree with you that prop is exempt. Maybe I should have written the entire scenario in my question, because I don't think its possible to refactor, as you suggested

Comment: Everything is refactorable! ;) I didn't mean to bash your usecase, just wanted to get you thinking about a clean API! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.fn.remove_elem = function(flag) {
if(flag)
  this.remove();
};
$( ".something").remove_elem (true);
```

Try this.